# Insert newlines between grep results while preserving colors

Tags: sed, grep

```
grep --color -C 0 -rni --exclude-dir="\node_modules" Login ./* | sed G
```

The above formats the lines in a way I like but the `--color` aspect of the grep command is lost. Is there are replacement for `sed G` that would preserve the highlight color?

Note that the `GREP_COLOR` env var needs to be set for `--color` to operate. An example:
`GREP_COLOR="1;46"`

Comment: Why are user voting to close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--color` is equivalent to `--color=auto`, meaning "color the output if writing to a terminal; otherwise, don't". You want it to color the output even when writing to a pipe, so you need to use `--color=always` instead:

```
grep --color=always -C 0 -rni --exclude-dir="\node_modules" Login ./* | sed G
```

(no change to the `sed` command is required.)

Comment: StackOverflow has a time buffer within which you cannot accept an answer yet—this does work.